# Add/Read configuration from an encrypted file

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core

I went down the path of creating my own `ConfigurationProvider`, which encrypts a file if it hasn't been already encrypted, and is also able to decrypt it.

I am now struggling coming up with a way of adding my decrypted appsettings.json content (decrypted string) to the configuration in a similar way that that `.AddJsonFile()` does.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to call `.AddEncryptedJson("appsettings.json")` in my `Startup.cs`, which would decrypt the file and add all the configuration necessary.

```
public class CustomConfigProvider : ConfigurationProvider, IConfigurationSource
{
    private readonly RSA _pubKey;
    private readonly RSA _privKey;
    private readonly string _filePath;

    public CustomConfigProvider(string filePath)
    {
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "certs", "IdentityServer4Auth.pfx"), "test");
        _pubKey = RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPublicKey(cert);
        _privKey = RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(cert);
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        Data = UnencryptMyConfiguration();
    }

    private IDictionary<string, string> UnencryptMyConfiguration()
    {
        EncryptIfNotEncrypted();

        var configFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_filePath);

        var decryptedData = _privKey.Decrypt(configFileBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);

        jsonString = jsonString.Trim(new char[] { '\uFEFF', '\u200B' });
        dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
        Dictionary<string, string> dictObj = result.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        return dictObj;
    }

    private void EncryptIfNotEncrypted()
    {
        var configFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_filePath);

        // Check if encrypted
        try
        {
            _privKey.Decrypt(configFileBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        }
        catch
        {
            var encryptedData = 
                _pubKey.Encrypt(configFileBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);

            using (var fs = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                fs.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
            }
        }
    }
    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        return new CustomConfigProvider(_filePath);
    }
}

public static class CustomConfigProviderExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddEncryptedJson(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, string filePath)
    {
        return builder.Add(new CustomConfigProvider(filePath));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by taking a peek at the internal `JsonConfigurationFileParser` class [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/74e22a1338443b0960109d491e6e561ef8f3d74a/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs) at the aspnet/Configuration repository.
By creating a similar class in your project, you'll be able to successfully parse the decrypted JSON string.

To use the parser, simply feed the `jsonString` as a `Stream` to its `Parse()`method. Your `UnencryptMyConfiguration()` method would then look like this:

```
private IDictionary<string, string> UnencryptMyConfiguration()
{
    EncryptIfNotEncrypted();

    var configFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_filePath);

    var decryptedData = _privKey.Decrypt(configFileBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
    var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);

    //treat the decrypted string as a Stream to let JsonConfigurationFileParser handle it
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var parser = new JsonConfigurationFileParser();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(jsonString);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return parser.Parse(stream);
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you brought this up. I actually ended up doing exactly that, although that class is internal, so I had to copy the code, instead of just reuse it